# Connecting to specific network from code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have a hardware product that is an `access point`. We would like the user to be able to connect to it in the first use for configurations.

Let's say the network name is "`test`".

Instead of sending the user to the Settings on the iPhone, and pick "`test`" network, I would like to stay in the app, and do that in there, automatically/or by hand, then send data to the network, so user will have a better experience.

Is it possible? I have read about `CoreWLAN`, is it relevant?

Comment: I believe that you need to use the *Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC) feature* that is available under the MFi program

Comment: oh no, we didn't wanted to go with MFi . I hope that connecting by hand from the settings is not requiring MFi (?)  i could see many others that do that..

Comment: No, you can connect using settings without MFi, but not from within your app AFAIK